# Can't access bloc in showDialog context in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I´m new in the bloc pattern. I want to show up an alert dialog when I press a button, but when I use showDialog func and showDialog I want to access Bloc from context or BlocListner doesn't contain bloc and throw error is there a way to access bloc in this situatuion

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocListener<TeacherFinancialCubit, TeacherFinancialState> Widget

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if(state is! Authorize) {
      return const BaBaFullScreenLoading();
    }
    return BlocProvider<TeacherFinancialCubit>(
      lazy: false,
      create: (context) => TeacherFinancialCubit(locator())..getTeacherFinancial(state.user, state.account, teacherId ?? 0),
      child: _masterLayout(context),
    );
  },
);
```

}

```
Widget _masterLayout(BuildContext context) {
Authorize authorize = context.read<UserBloc>().state as Authorize;
return MasterLayout(
  showBack: true,
  floatingActionButton: authorize.account.type == master ? FloatingActionButton(
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      Future.microtask(() => _showAddPaymentDialog(context));
    },
  ) : null,
  title: const Text(""),
  child: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
    child: _showTeacherFinancials(context, authorize),
  ),
);
```

}

```
void _showAddPaymentDialog(BuildContext context) async {
return showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return BlocListener<TeacherFinancialCubit, TeacherFinancialState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if(state is TeacherFinancialLoading) {
            EasyLoadingHelper.showLoading();
          }
          else {
            EasyLoadingHelper.dismiss();
            if(state is TeacherFinancialFailed) {
              EasyLoadingHelper.showToastError(context, message: state.error);
            }
            else if(state is TeacherFinancialSuccess) {
              EasyLoadingHelper.showToastSuccess(context, message: successMessage);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          }
        },
        child: AlertDialog(
          title: const Text(''),
          content: Form(
            key: addPaymentFormKey,
            child: Text(""),
          ),
          actions: [],
        ),
      );
    }
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to provide the bloc to the AlertDialog. You can do something like this:

```
return showDialog(
  ...
  builder: (dialogContext) => BlocProvider.value(
    value: BlocProvider.of<TeacherFinancialCubit>(context),
    child: BlocListener<TeacherFinancialCubit, TeacherFinancialState>(
      ...
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me I got the following error؛ BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a TeacherFinancialCubit.

Comment: This should work, if it doesn't work, please check your context passed into the _showAddPaymentDialog function can access TeacherFinancialCubit. You can check that by adding context.read< TeacherFinancialCubit >() as the first line in the _showAddPaymentDialog function. If it does show error, means, your context itself doesn't have access to TeacherFinancialCubit.

Comment: Can someone explain why is this (providing bloc explicitly) necessary? Couldn't showDialog look up itself?

Comment: It is not the same context tree. So cannot look it up.